# SVN: Creating alias that allows filename variable

Tags: git, svn, alias

With SVN is there a way to store a quick alias for:

```
svn log -q filename | grep '^r' | cut -f1 -d' '
```

Where I could use something like `svn log filename` and the filename would be plugged into the long command above?

I've used some aliases using GIT like one for `hist`, but was unsure of how SVN works with things like this:

```
hist = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, Subversion has no alias facility like Git.  You could do it through your shell with a shell function.  For instance, something like `svnhist() { svn log -q "$@" | grep '^r' | cut -f1 -d' ' }`.

Comment: @jszakmeister Dang. Do you simple code the function directly into the smell or is there a file I edit to run the function?

Comment: You can just put the line into your .bashrc file.  You'll need to restart any shells you have, but once you do, it will be there for you.  To use it, you'd just run `svnhist filename` right from the command line, like you would any other executable.

Comment: @jszakmeister I added `$ function svnhist() { svn log -q "$@" | grep '^r' | cut -f1 -d' ' }` to `.bashrc` and even `.bash_profile` with no luck. Using Terminal on Mac. Something I am missing?

Comment: Do you already have an existing `.bashrc` that you know is being sourced?  Also, I have the function slightly wrong (for a one liner), it should be: `svnhist() { svn log -q "$@" | grep '^r' | cut -f1 -d' ' ; }` (note the semi-colon after the `cut` command).  On my Mac (10.6.8), `.bash_profile` is being run, and it's sourcing my `.bashrc`.  I seem to remember some goofiness about things getting sourced correctly, but can't remember what I had to do (and it may have been for zsh, not bash).

Comment: @jszakmeister Totally didn't see the missing semicolon also. Got that plugged in and it works! I still currently have it in `.bash_profile`. Is there any reason to move it to `.bashrc`?

Comment: Nope.  Sounds like you're good to go. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @jszakmeister:

Plugged: `svnhist() { svn log -q "$@" | grep '^r' | cut -f1 -d' ' ; }`

Into `.bash_profile`